# JMeter OS Process Sampler redirect to Log Viewer

Tags: logging, jmeter

I'm running a `.jar` file from JMeter. This executable can take time to complete. e.g. 5 minutes. During that period there is no console output on the Log Viewer. An entry only shows up in a *View Results Tree* once the jar finishes. Then I can see the logs generated by the `.jar` under `Response data`.

The lack of feedback for ~5 minutes is a poor experience. I want to change this by redirecting the `.jar` logs to the log viewer. Is this possible?

I see the OS Process Sampler has a redirect to file option. Does it have any support for redirecting to Log Viewer? Or is there an alternative sampler I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is:

1. Instead of calling the .jar file from the OS Process Sampler call it from [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), only one line of code will be required.
2. Implement the logging you need in the .jar file using [SLF4J library](http://www.slf4j.org/)
3. [Configure the relevant logging level if needed in JMeter's log4j2.xml file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Comment: `only one line of code will be required` - that sounds promising but it has eluded me.